# data transformation in regression

Tags: regression, logarithm

I am going through a research paper on HbA1C (hemoglobin) management of diabetic patients. The author has used multilevel model as it has repeated measures. The DV has been log transformed. To calculate the change in the DV, the author has computed a formula [10^(coefficient of the factor) - 1]. I dont understand the idea behind this.. Can someone please help me what could be "10^(coefficient of the factor) - 1"[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably what is going on is that the original transformation was not log10(hemoglobin) but log10(hemoglobin + 1).  This sort of thing is often done if the variable (here, hemoglobin) is sometimes 0 but a log transformation is still desired.

Then they back-transformed it to get to the original scale which is more intuitively meaningful - at least, for people in the field.

Comment: Yes, arshad, but I don't think it's correct.  The footnote says this is the formula for the *change* in AIC (which presumably names the response variable). It merely is supposing that when $1$ is added to the regressor, the log response will increase by the slope estimate $\hat\beta \times 1 = \hat\beta$. The original AIC value $y$ becomes $y 10^{\hat\beta}$ and the change, therefore, is $$y 10^{\hat\beta} - y = (10^{\hat\beta} - 1)y.$$ That's the meaning of the value $10^{\hat\beta} - 1$.

Comment: A bit more reading on variable transformation made me more confused. What I understand is if DV is log transformed, then interpretation would be -- DV changes by 100*(coefficient) percent for a one unit increase in the IV. If this is true, shouldn't the interpretation of IV "insurance" in the above table be like the following - Using the insured as the reference group, the uninsured had a 2.2% higher A1C level.  Thanks